# reCAPTCHA and JS form validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, recaptcha

I am new to the Google `reCAPTCHA` and I am trying to implement this to an existing form validation.

This is my original code:

```
if(document.getElementById('naam').value.length == '' || document.getElementById('firma').value.length == '' || !filter_email.test(email.value)|| document.getElementById('bericht').value.length == '') {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true; }
    else {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false; }
```

Since I am new to `reCAPTCHA` I have been looking into a lot of online documents but they all are describing a different implementation.

I was hoping to simply implement it like:

```
if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "success" || document.getElementById('naam').value.length == '' || document.getElementById('firma').value.length == '' || !filter_email.test(email.value)|| document.getElementById('bericht').value.length == '') {
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true; }
else {
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false; }
```

But that seems not to work, how to implement this so this correctly in my existing code?

**EDIT 2**
When using Invisible reCAPTCHA as suggested by Ralph Melhem I have changed my submit button to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Verstuur e-mail" class="g-recaptcha btn btn-info pull-right" data-sitekey="xxxx" data-callback="YourOnSubmitFn" disabled>
```

And kept my original form validation, but then the form is not send I see this error in the console `ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: YourOnSubmitFn`

**EDIT 3**

My new code now looks like:

```
<!-- reCAPTCHA -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<script>
function onSubmit(token) {
  document.getElementById("contact").submit();
}
</script>

<form name="contact" action="#" method="post">

<div class="col-lg-6">

    <div class="form-group input-group" id="naam_div">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="naam" name="naam" value="" placeholder="Uw naam" onkeyup="validate()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" id="naam_glyp"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group input-group" id="firma_div">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firma" name="firma" value="" placeholder="Uw firma" onkeyup="validate()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" id="firma_glyp"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group input-group" id="email_div">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Uw email adres" onkeyup="validate()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" id="email_glyp"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group input-group" id="bericht_div">
      <textarea name="bericht" id="bericht" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Type hier uw bericht" onkeyup="validate()"></textarea>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback" id="bericht_glyp"></span>
    </div>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Verstuur e-mail" class="g-recaptcha btn btn-info pull-right" data-sitekey="*************" data-callback="onSubmit" data-size="invisible" disabled>

</div>

</form>

<script>
function validate()
{
    // naam
    if(document.getElementById('naam').value.length == '') {
        document.getElementById('naam_div').className = "form-group input-group has-feedback";
        document.getElementById('naam_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"; }
    else {
        document.getElementById('naam_div').className = "form-group input-group has-feedback";
        document.getElementById('naam_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"; }

    // firma
    if(document.getElementById('firma').value.length == '') {
        document.getElementById('firma_div').className = "form-group input-group has-feedback";
        document.getElementById('firma_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"; }
    else {
        document.getElementById('firma_div').className = "form-group input-group has-feedback";
        document.getElementById('firma_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"; }

    // email
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var filter_email = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if(document.getElementById('email').value == false) {
        document.getElementById('email_div').className = "form-group input-group has-feedback";
        document.getElementById('email_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"; }
    else if (!filter_email.test(email.value)) {
        document.getElementById('email_div').className = "form-group input-group has-error has-feedback";
        document.getElementById('email_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"; }
    else {
        document.getElementById('email_div').className = "form-group input-group has-feedback";
        document.getElementById('email_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"; }

    // bericht
    if(document.getElementById('bericht').value.length == '') {
        document.getElementById('bericht_div').className = "form-group input-group has-feedback";
        document.getElementById('bericht_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"; }
    else {
        document.getElementById('bericht_div').className = "form-group input-group has-feedback";
        document.getElementById('bericht_glyp').className = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"; }

    // submit form
    if(document.getElementById('naam').value.length == '' || document.getElementById('firma').value.length == '' || !filter_email.test(email.value)|| document.getElementById('bericht').value.length == '') {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true; }
    else {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false; }
}
</script>
```

The live version is [here](https://torza.nl/test.php).

When I use `data-callback="onSubmit"` I have this error in my console `Uncaught (in promise) null`
And if I use `data-callback="dataFallback"` I have this error `ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: dataFallback`

Comment: which version of google reCAPTCHA are you using?

Comment: I am using reCAPTCHA v2

Comment: Why not use Invisible reCAPTCHA? it's the simplest to implement, and requires no interaction with the users

Comment: Ok, that seems fair. I have generated an new code, but can I add my existing validation to that?

Answer (score 2):

For the invisible reCaptcha, you can set your form button as follows:

```
<button class="g-recaptcha btn btn-primary standard-button2 ladda-button" data-sitekey="YOURSITEKEY" data-callback="dataFallback"  data-size="invisible" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" data-style="expand-left">Send Message</button>
```

and include the script

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script>
   function onSubmit(token) {
     document.getElementById("YOURFORMNAME").submit();
   }
 </script>
```

This will handle the validation you're trying to achieve.
If you still want to do it your way, I can help you clean it up, but I believe the above way is the most non-invasive for your code

Comment: Be careful, remove your sitekey from the question.
Disable it and create a new on for production, as this one is tainted now :) 

as for the error, in your input field you have data-callback="YourOnSubmitFn"
replace that with data-callback="dataFallback" or data-callback='onSubmit' and you should be fine

Comment: With the changes I am nog getting is error `Uncaught (in promise) null`

Comment: Do you have this available online so we can reach it and see what's happening?

Comment: Yes you can: torza.nl/test.php

Comment: In the script above, you need to replace "YOURFORMNAME" with the name tag on your form. I can see in your code that you don't have that, so add it and it will work. (<form name="iLovePHP">) 

and then the script should say: document.getElementById("iLovePHP").submit();

Comment: Please check my 3rd edit of the original post. Thank you.

Comment: when the data-callback was set to onSubmit, i tried it and it was working fine without an error, try to put it back and comment again so i can check it

Comment: I have set is back to `onSubmit`

Comment: it's my mistake, you should reference the form by ID not by name since the script is using getElementById :)

Comment: you changed your data fallback again, read your console errors mate :) 
ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: dataFallback

Comment: Yes, and `data-callback="onSubmit"` gives the error `Uncaught (in promise) null`